# how implement a button in customized UITableViewCell in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I tried to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305794/correct-way-to-setting-a-tag-to-all-cells-in-tableview) but is not working.
what I want i s a button in my customized cell that knows data from the array that is used from the tableview (later I'll apply it to CoreData), for example, print the value of the array that generated the tableview.

but I cannot understand how to do it

I have a customized cell class, where I tried to use **both a button action or a outlet button (with tags):**

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var myCellImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myCellLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}





}
```

and a ViewController where is my tableview with an extension

```
extension ViewController {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comicsArray.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    cell.myCellLabel.text = String(indexPath.row)
    cell.myCellButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.myCellButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("logAction:"), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}


func logAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let titleString = self.comicsArray[sender.tag]

    let firstActivityItem = "\(titleString)"

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



}
```

**EDIT:**

solved with help of abdullahselek by adding in subclasses cell:

```
public var dataFromTableView : String!
```

and implementing:

```
@IBAction func myCellButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {


    guard dataFromTableView != nil else {return}

    print("pushed \(dataFromTableView!)")


}
```

and in cellForRowAt :

```
    cell.data = comicsArray[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: You can use delegates

Comment: Hi GeneCode, how could I use them?

Comment: Im dont know swift. But here is example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29724262/501439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a dictionary or object model property to your custom tableviewcell like

```
public var data: Dictionary!
```

And set this data property

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    ...

    cell.data = comicsArray[indexPath.row]

}
```

Then you button can reach data with in your tableviewcell

Comment: as dictionary is not working but :     public var data : String!
is working! do you think it would be a proper way to manage even data from  a core data entity?

Comment: then you have just string values in your array I don't think using core data entity is a must for string values

Comment: oh, this is only a test, in order to pass/modify data from the array (wich will have data from core data) to the button

Comment: I suggest to use this database library [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa)